# SwiftUI - View with a VStack initialized once but the body is called twice

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

Why, in SwiftUI, the body gets called twice when we use a `VStack`?

Example without a `VStack`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
  }
}
```

By placing a breaking point at `Text("Hello World")`, I can see the function `body` runs a single time, as I expected.

If I slightly change this code by including a `VStack`, the situation changes:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack { Text("Hello World") }
  }
}
```

Now, if I place the breakpoint at the same line, I can see the function `body` is called twice.

Why exactly does this happen? Why just by the inclusion of a `VStack` SwiftUI needs to run `body` again?

Comment: I would like to see some answers to this as I have a similar issue though my code is a little different.